# Using select dropdowns in a form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use HTML select dropdowns to help sort the search results on my website and I am having some trouble. In the code below, I specifically select Option1 and when I try to echo the result after I submit the form, it always echo's 'FAIL'. I was wondering if someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong and what is the proper way to retrieve the data from the option the user selected, after the form was submitted?

```
<?php 

echo '<form method="post" action="search.php">
    <select>
         <option name="one">Option1 </option>
             <option name="two">Option2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="searchword" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search"  />
</form>';



if(isset($_POST['one'])){
     echo 'Option1 is set';
}else{
     echo 'FAIL';
}

?>
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the name attribute goes with the `select` tag.

```
<select name="dropdown">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
</select>

if(isset($_POST['dropdown'])) {
    echo $_POST['dropdown']; //echoes 'Option 1'
}
```

If you like, you can add a `value` attribute to the `option` element, but you don't have to.

If you do

```
<option value="foobar">Option1</option>
```

The form will post `foobar` and not `Option1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

echo '<form method="post" action="search.php">
    <select name="my_option">
         <option value="one">Option1 </option>
             <option value="two">Option2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="searchword" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search"  />
</form>';



echo "My option value is : " .  $_POST['my_option'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your select tag and access that instead.

`<select name="options"></select>`

`echo $_POST['options'];` will give you your selected option

Answer (score 0):

Instead of name="one" an option needs a

```
value="myvalue"
```

and your select tag needs an

```
name="nameofthisthinghere"
```

Comment: You're correct, but I'd like to point out that the `value` attribute is optional.